# How can I Install vim plugin offline?

Tags: gvim, plugin-system

I am currently using gvim. I want to know is it possible to install a vim plugin offline?

I have the project files already downloaded from github, and I want to put them in the right locations for vim to source them.

Comment: How can I improve my post?

Comment: I didn't see this question at the time, but in case you're still wondering, the question wasn't closed because it was *bad*, the question was closed because it's a *duplicate*: several of the answers to the linked question discuss where you can put files you have already downloaded in order for Vim to load the plugin when it starts.